# How to get date range from the user?

Tags: android, date, android-datepicker

Actually I didn't think to write a question like this. I expected to found the solution when investigating first time, but couldn't. Even the issue seems basic and common, it became problematic.

Problem : Getting a date range from the user

What I thought and found :

- Show two different date pickers to the user, store dates. Subtract one to other and get the date range. (Seems to bad practice)
- Using Android Material Library Date Range Picker.
  (As far as I understood, material components recently started to provide this (after middle 2019)). How to handle customization?.

  ```
      MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker =
              MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker().build();

      materialDatePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), null);

      materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {

              androidx.core.util.Pair date = (androidx.core.util.Pair) selection ;

              Log.i(Statics.LOGTAG, date.first.toString());
              Log.i(Statics.LOGTAG, date.second.toString());

          }
      });
  ```

What I want to achieve :

[image]

Thank you for reading this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use this library: https://github.com/savvisingh/DateRangePicker

Comment: add custom dialog that contains two date pickers in it, and just create the method that returns the date range when you click on "OK" (I don't know how are you using the data, so I'd suggest you to return it as a string).   
Or, if you prefer doing it in library, I'd suggest the squares [times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) library - from my personal experience, it's pretty customizable.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I don't prefer third party libraries as much as possible. I will go for your recommendation if no better choice won't be suggested